# What are some use cases of Named Routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

After reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes), I still only have a vague idea of what Named Routes are in Laravel.

Could you help me understand?

```php
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    //
})->name('profile');
```

```php
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->name('profile');
```

It says:

> Once you have assigned a name to a given route, you may use the route's name when generating URLs or redirects via the global route function

I don't understand what the second part of the sentence means, about generating URLs or redirects.

What would be a generated URL in the case of `profile` from the above example? How would I use it?

Comment: In your application (regardless if it's in a view, controller etc), I would recommend that you only refer to named routes and never the actual URL's. If you then need to change the URL of some request, it will automatically resolve to the correct URL everywhere. If you hard code the URL's in your application, you would need to update the URL everywhere you've used it.

Comment: In your example, `route('profile')` would return `user/profile` since it's that route that has the name `profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource is right here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

One of the common use case is in your views. Say your post request goes to a particular route, basically without named routes you can simply go like this to store a task

```
action="/task"
```

but say for example you need to update the route to /task/store , you will need to update it everywhere you use the route.

But consider you used a named route

```
Route::post('/task', 'TaskController@store')->name('task.store');
```

With named routes you can use the route like this in your view:

```
action="{{route('task.store')}}"
```

Now if you choose to update your route, you only need to make the change in the routes file and update it to whatever you need.

```
Route::post('/task/now/go/here', 'TaskController@store')->name('task.store');
```

If you need to pass arguments to your routes, you pass it as arguments to route helper like this:

```
route('task.edit', 1), // in resource specific example it will output /task/1/edit
```

All of the view examples are given you use blade templating.

Comment: A different question, but I am wondering, why not just use `name('task')` instead of `name('task.store')`? Is this just a convention in Laravel, for writing cleaner code?

Comment: @tadadadadi
I used laravel's resource convention. Basically a laravel resource consists of 5 routes. For task resource, it be like task.index, task.create, task.store, task.update, task.destroy.  Each to show all tasks, show form to create task, store task, update task, delete task, respectively.

So yes, its just convention.

Answer (score 2):

After adding a name to a route, you can use the `route()` helper to create urls.
 This can now be used in your application.

For instance, in your blade templates this  may look like:

```
{{ route('profile') }}
```

This will use the application url and the route path to create a url.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Understood and thank you for adding. Was just giving an example of how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

this is how it looks it:

named route sample `name('store');`:

```
Route::get('/store-record','YourController@function')->name('store');
```

`store` is the named route here. to call it use `route('store')`

defining another type of route. this is not named route:

```
Route::get('/store-record','YourController@function')
```

you can access this route using `{{ url('/store-record') }}`

hope this helps